# Cross compiling libSDL

Tags: linux, compilation, sdl, cross-compiling, configure

I'm trying to cross-compile libSDL version 1.2 for a custom made, debian based Linux system. The toolchain I'm using is already configured properly so that I just run gcc/g++ on my the desired code and the resulting output is compatible with the target machine.

When I run `./configure --help` in the libSDL source directory, I see that I can basically just set some environment variables to point to my cross-compiler.

However, I also see the following options:

```
System types:
  --build=BUILD     configure for building on BUILD [guessed]
  --host=HOST       cross-compile to build programs to run on HOST [BUILD]
```

I looked into the `configure.in`, `build-scripts/config.sub`, and `build-scripts/config.guess` files but couldn't really figure out how it works.

Are these options required? If not, is it a good idea to use them? If it's a good idea to use them, how do I get a list of the possible values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should indeed set both of these.

Assuming your cross-compiler lives in /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32 and that your system host is called x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, you should configure it like so:

```
configure \
  --prefix=/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32 \
  --build=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu \
  --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32
```

It's actually quite easy! :)

Comment: Okay perfect, so for the `--host` flag should I put `x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu` because that's the system type, or `i686-pc-linux-gnu` because that's how I'm building the application (32bit)? And for the `--build` flag, does it matter what I put? The point of cross-compiling is to use a toolchain so the host system doesn't really matter

Comment: It does matter what you put into the --build flag because this way the configure script can detect that you are cross-compiling. I'm not sure how exactly this helps but it probably tries harder to make the build work then, or something. :)

It will even tell you that it's now cross-compiling if --build and --host differ.